# How to Instantiate User control in Master page cs file

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, master-pages, user-controls

I have added uc in contentplace holder of master page but how do you instantiate the user control in master page .cs file to make it visible when the master page loads

Answer (score 3):

If you add it to a ContentPlaceHolder, and a child page adds content to that ContentPlaceHolder - you're user control will no longer appear. IOW, the controls you add are only the *default*.

Just add it outside of the ContentPlaceHolder if you want it always visible.

Comment: In other words... any tags placed inside a ContentPlaceHolder on a master page will function as default content, but generally they are replaced by the tags inside the corresponding Content tag of a content page, unless the content page omits such a corresponding Content tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive but I think you need to use the Page.LoadControl() to officially load a user control to a page at run time.

Comment: User controls loaded at runtime need to be loaded with LoadControl, rather than "new MyUserControl", because otherwise the control's tags aren't parsed and none of the control's child objects will be instantiated.  That will result in surprises like unexpected null controls and problems restoring viewstate.  But anyway, for this particular question, I think it's just what Mark Brackett said... the stuff inside the ContentPlaceHolder *on the master page* is getting replaced by the stuff in the corresponding Content tag of the child page (unless content page omits mentioned corresponding tag).

Answer (score 0):

If I read this correctly, you have a control in a Master page and need to reference it from the child pages to change it's visibility? Or have I got things around the wrong way?

Anyway, here's how I commonly do it in VB .Net, it shouldn't be too hard to port ;-)

In the aspx page:

```
<%@ Reference Control="~/path/to/my/customControl.ascx" %>
```

In the code-behind:

```
Dim customControl As ASP.customcontrol_ascx = Master.FindControl("customControl")
If customControl IsNot Nothing Then
    ...
End If
```